# Confusion with return statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to invoke or call a function with return statement first i write `return` and then function name followed by parenthesis we can use `return` for returning a reference of a function but can i call a function with `return` statement  if not then why?
below is my code for that what i am trying to perform

```js
function make() {
  var count = 0;

  function counter() {
    count = count + 1;
    return count;
  }
  // here i ma calling a function with return statement return functionname followed by paranthesis
  return counter()
}
var result = make();
console.log(result());
console.log(result())
console.log(result())
```

Comment: Just `return counter`

Answer (score 2):

You use a closure over `count`, you need to return the function reference to the inner function.

This function is later called and the actual count is returned from `counter`.

```js
function make() {
    function counter() {
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
    }

    var count = 0;
    return counter;
}

var result = make();

console.log(result());
console.log(result());
console.log(result());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run make all that happens is that you declare a variable and a function. You are then executing that function, which returns the `counter`. But, then you are trying to log the results of executing that `counter`, which is not a function. If you remove the parenthesis from the `.log` statements, you can see the number.

```js
  function make(){
    var count=0;
    function counter(){
      count=count+1;
      return count;
    }
    // here i ma calling a function with return statement return functionname followed by paranthesis
    return counter()
  }

  var result=make();    // This returns the counter, not a function
  console.log(result);  // result is a number, not a function
  console.log(result)
  console.log(result)
```